# Cross product of two sums of three vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

This seems like a simple question but I couldn't find anywhere to verify

Is it true that:

$$(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c})\times (\mathbf{d}+\mathbf{e}+\mathbf{f})
=
(\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{d})+(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{e})+(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{f})
+ 
(\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{d})+(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{e})+(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{f})
+
(\mathbf{c}\times \mathbf{d})+(\mathbf{c}\times\mathbf{e})+(\mathbf{c}\times\mathbf{f})
$$

Just wondering whether the following identity is true.

Comment: Yes: it is true due to distributivity of the cross product. You can have an arbitrary number of summands and this remains true.

Comment: Cross product is bilinear so this is possible.

Comment: Hint: Use the identities $(\mathbf{a+b})\mathbf{\times c=a\times c+b\times c}$ and $\mathbf{c\times}(\mathbf{a+b})\mathbf{=c\times a+c\times b}$ repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

This was already ansered in comments, so I'll just write it in answers from Colescu's comment.
We know that the cross product is distributive, meaning $(a+b)\times c=a\times c + b \times c$ and $c×(a+b)=c×a+c×b$

We can do this a bunch of times from the left to arrive to the right side of the equation $(a+b+c)×(d+e+f)=(a×d)+(a×e)+(a×f)+(b×d)+(b×e)+(b×f)+(c×d)+(c×e)+(c×f)$

So we start with $(a+b+c)×(d+e+f)$, We'll keep using the distributive propiety until we arrive at the desired equation.

$$(a+b+c)×(d+e+f)$$
$$=(a+[b+c])×(d+e+f)$$
$$=(a×(d+e+f))+([b+c]×(d+e+f))$$
$$=(a×(d+e+f))+(b×(d+e+f))+(c×(d+e+f))$$
$$=(a×(d+[e+f]))+(b×(d+[e+f]))+(c×(d+[e+f]))$$
$$=(a×d+a×[e+f])+(b×d+b×[e+f])+(c×d+c×[e+f])$$
$$=(a×d+a×e+a×f)+(b×d+b×e+b×f)+(c×d+c×e+c×f)$$
$$=(a×d)+(a×e)+(a×f)+(b×d)+(b×e)+(b×f)+(c×d)+(c×e)+(c×f)$$